# How to refer to historical data from latest to oldest?

Tags: word-order, lists

Consider I have a a list of 5 exercises I did, sorted from most recent to oldest.

- Exercise 1
- Exercise 2
- Exercise 3
- Exercise 4
- Exercise 5

So the last exercise I did is Exercise 1. My question is how do I refer to exercise 2/3/4/5?

Is exercise 2 the second to last exercise? Isn't last in this list exercise 5? I'm a bit confused as to what second to last would mean here. Is last the last exercise I did or last in the list.

Can anyone clarify please?

EDIT: Is what I'm looking for the following? Is this the proper way to refer to the exercises?

- Latest
- First Latest
- Second Latest
- Third Latest
- Fourth Latest

Comment: Yup, just clocked that. I believe what I'm looking for is something along the lines of "first latest", "second latest', etc. Is that the proper way to refer to the ordered exercises?

Comment: The one before that, the one before *that*, another prior, and the earliest one. Or, in chronological order, ... the first exercise, the second exercise, etc.

Comment: @Lawrence first exercise, second exercise, etc. doesn't capture the dimension of the list being reverse chronological order...I really though there'd be a two word way of describing this situation...

Comment: @NigelJ Don't ask, this has been bugging me for a while. It's for an app I'm developing where I need to be able to refer to previously completed exercises with a two word constraint.

Comment: You would have to define what you mean by 'last'. Do you mean the last exercise performed in time, or do you mean the exercise numbered last, numerically ?

Comment: @NigelJ assuming that I clarify beforehand that last exercise refers to the last exercise performed in time, does second last exercise then refer to Exercise 2?

Comment: I've up-voted this question because it's the craziest thing I've seen in quite a while. I'm now off duty and will drive in reverse all the way home in order to save on fuel.

Comment: @NigelJ hahaha, you get to wind down your mileage too - it's a win for you. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: The second last exercise performed is indeed Exercise 2. Did you time travel here all by yourself or did someone force you to do it :) ?